# Argument(s) are different! Wanted: Actual invocation has different arguments:

Tags: junit, mockito

ServiceClass:

```
public void createManualEvaluationReductionChangeHistory(Long key, String accountId, RegisterReductionPerFunction registerReductionPerFunction, String languageCode, String comments, String pagRedFlag) {
    ProfessionalCustomerHistory professionalCustomerHistory = new ProfessionalCustomerHistory();
    professionalCustomerHistory.setDescription(comments);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setReductionCategory(registerReductionPerFunction.getReductionCategoryCode());
    professionalCustomerHistory.setReductionType(registerReductionPerFunction.getReductionTypeCode());
    professionalCustomerHistory.setValidityId(registerReductionPerFunction.getValidityId().longValue());
    professionalCustomerHistory.setReductionPercentage(reductionCategoryService.getReductionPercentage(languageCode,
            registerReductionPerFunction.getReductionCategoryCode(), registerReductionPerFunction.getReductionTypeCode()));
    professionalCustomerHistory.setTotalReduction(professionalCustomerHistory.getReductionPercentage());
    professionalCustomerHistory.setPagFixedReductionFlag(pagRedFlag);
    setCommonHistoryDetails(professionalCustomerHistory, Constants.NO, accountId, key, Constants.HISTORY_TYPE_REDUCTIONS);
    professionalCustomerHistoryDlService.create(professionalCustomerHistory);
}
```

Junit Test:
  @Test

```
public void createManualEvaluationReductionChangeHistory() {

    ProfessionalCustomerHistory professionalCustomerHistory = new ProfessionalCustomerHistory();
    RegisterReductionPerFunction registerReductionPerFunction = new RegisterReductionPerFunction();
    professionalCustomerHistory.setValidityId(1L);
    registerReductionPerFunction.setValidityId(1);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setProfCustomerId(PROF_CUST_ID);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setHistoryType("RD");
    professionalCustomerHistory.setEditedBy(ACCOUNT_ID);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setHistoryDate(new Date());
    professionalCustomerHistory.setNoDeleteFlag("N");
    professionalCustomerHistory.setReductionPercentage(null);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setTotalReduction(null);
    professionalCustomerHistory.setDescription(COMMENTS);
    Mockito.when(reductionCategoryService.getReductionPercentage(LANGUAGE_CODE, null, null)).thenReturn(null);
    profCustomerHistoryService.createManualEvaluationReductionChangeHistory(PROF_CUST_ID, ACCOUNT_ID.toString(), registerReductionPerFunction, LANGUAGE_CODE, COMMENTS, null);
    Mockito.verify(reductionCategoryService).getReductionPercentage(LANGUAGE_CODE,null,null);
    Mockito.verify(professionalCustomerHistoryDlService).create(professionalCustomerHistory);
}
```

When i am testing it getting below error.

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
Actual invocation has different arguments:

But i see all the parameters are exact the same. what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] and the info which of your `verify` calls fails? Does `ProfessionalCustomerHistory` implement proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods?

Comment: ProfessionalCustomerHistory is a DB entity, i dont have equals and hashcode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ProfessionalCustomerHistory is a DB entity, i dont have `equals` and `hashcode`

Assuming that its only your 2nd `verify` that fails, this is the problem.

Currently you create a different `ProfessionalCustomerHistory` object in your test and in your logic. They might have the same content but without properly implemented `equals` and `hashcode` methods, the default implementation in java only cares about the object reference.

If you use an IDE it probably has some generate method that lets you generate the proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

---

If you only want to validate that the correct method is called, without caring about the exact content, you could use:

```
Mockito.verify(professionalCustomerHistoryDlService)
       .create(Mockito.any(ProfessionalCustomerHistory.class));
```

---

If you can not or do not want to change the `ProfessionalCustomerHistory` class, you could use an `ArgumentCaptor` and compare the distinct fields afterwards.

Comment: resolved it.
professionalCustomerHistory.setHistoryDate(new Date());
In the above line date is being set with different milliSeconds. i have just implemented equals hashcode excluding date. it is working fine now.
Thank you for your time